# JS Regex - Replace multiple instances in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, str-replace

I have this string:

```
var str = '"testFN, II testLN, II" < test1@test.com>, "testFN, Cal testLN, Cal" < test2@test.com>';
```

and I am doing

```
str.replace(/(".*?),(.*?")/g, '$1__comma_$2');
```

to replace multiple commas(,) with in a string(__comma_), only inside "".

Event though I given /g its not replacing the all instances. It replace only first match of each instance.

Actual Result: "testFN__comma_ II testLN, II" < test1@test.com>, "testFN__comma_ testLN, Cal" < test2@test.com>
Expected Result: "testFN__comma_ II testLN__comma_ II" < test1@test.com>, "testFN__comma_ Cal testLN__comma_ Cal" < test2@test.com>

Can you please give any suggestions that I am missing anything ?

Comment: Use a non-greedy quantifier (`.*?`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try lazy quantifier:

```
(".*?,)(.*?")
```

However your replacements wouldn't take effect as you are not replacing that comma! So I'm going to modify your regex a little bit:

```
(".*?),(.*?")
```

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/yB9aA3/1)**

#### Update

Based on your new update, I made another regex which is totally different from previous one.

```
str.replace(/(,)(?=[^"]*[^\s]")/g, '__comma_');
```

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/yB9aA3/2)**

Comment: Hi revo, still some cases its not working fine. If my str = '"test, FN testLN, II" < test1@test.com>, "test, FN testLN, Cal" < test2@test.com>'; then its remove the first comma only in each instances. Could you please help me out this?

Comment: @RameshRaja Update your question.

Comment: Great revo, Can you please suggest me some good online tutorial to learn regex in depth?

Comment: @RameshRaja Start with [Introducing Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920012337.do) then it's worth it to read [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do)